# Hibernate like query on Many-to-Many collection

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I am having `User`entity which has mapped to `user_roles`. I want to filter these roles based on `User.id`and `roles.name`

Same like as this SQL query

```
SELECT ur 
FROM user 
     JOIN user_roles ur 
          ON ur.user_id = user.id 
WHERE user.id = 1 
  AND ur.name like '%admin%';
```

How to achieve this SQL query in hibernate?
How to pass parameter to role name?

User.java

```
@Entity
class User {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="user_roles",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(
            name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(
            name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
        )
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will help

```
select "your_req" from User us join usr.role usr where usr.name like '%admin%' and us.id=1
```

Comment: I want to pass user.id and ur.name as parameters

Comment: yes obviously you can pass that to the where clause of the query

Answer (score 0):

HQL supports exactly what you want, you can create an HQL query and then pass parameters to it. The following code block may be a reference:

```
Long userId = 1L;
String roleNamePattern = "%admin%";

Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT role FROM User user JOIN user.roles role WHERE user.id = :userid AND role.name LIKE :rolename");
query.setLong("userid", userId);
query.setString("rolename", roleNamePattern);
List<Role> roles = query.list();
```